# Sharing the same instance of the class in python across multiple files

Tags: python, database, configuration

I have stored the configurations of my project in database.Now I want to hit database only once ie when my project starts and want to cache all the configurations in my project.In all the python files of my project I want to use these configuration values.

But the problem I am facing is that inspite of using singleton pattern I am getting new instance of the class.This is my code:

ConfigFactory.py

```
class ConfigFactory:
    def __new__(cls, source):
       if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
          cls.instance = super(ConfigFactory, cls).__new__(cls)
          cls.instance.intialize(source)
       return cls.instance

    def initialize(self, source):
        if source == "database":
            connection = DB.connect_to_database()
            self.configuration = configFromDB(connection)

    def createConfiguration(self):
       return self.configuration


#Base Class
class Configuration:
   def getConfig(self):
      pass

   def loadConfigs(self):
      pass

class configFromDB(Configuration):
     def __new__(cls, source):
       if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
          cls.instance = super(configFromDB, cls).__new__(cls)
          cls.instance.intialize(connection)
       return cls.instance

      def initialize(self, connection):
          self.list = {}
          self.loaded = False
          self.connection = connection

      def loadConfigs(self):
          if not self.loaded:
              self.list = dict(DB.get_all_configurations())
              self.loaded = True

      def getConfig(self, key):
          if not self.loaded:
               self.loadConfigs()
          return self.list.get(key)
```

Now I have many python files like file1.py, file2.py where I want to access values I have cached in list variable of configFromDB class.But the problem that I am facing is that in every file I am not able to get this same instance.I need a solution so that I can access this same instance in all my files.Thanks in advance for help